# ArrayAdapter replace all values in listview

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-arrayadapter

I have a class called AddItemArrayAdapter that populates one listview with a button and an EditText that is in Main.axml. But when I add a new item, all row receive the new value.

AddItemArrayAdapter.cs

```
public class AddItemArrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<string>
{
    List<string> _ListOfText = new List<string> ();
    Context _Context;
    int _Resorce;
    string lastText;


    public AddItemArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, List<string> ListOfText) 
        : base(context,resource, ListOfText)
    {
        this._Context = context;
        this._Resorce = resource;
        this._ListOfText =  ListOfText;
    }

    public string GetLastItem()
    {
        lastText = _ListOfText[(_ListOfText.Count - 1)];

        return lastText;
    }

    public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater)_Context.GetSystemService (Context.LayoutInflaterService);

        View rowView;

        rowView = inflate.Inflate (Resource.Layout.newTextFromEdit , parent, false);

        TextView textView = rowView.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.singleText);

        textView.Text = GetLastItem();

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Button Click in MainActivity.cs:

```
btnAddItem.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    string textFromEditText = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.textFromEdit ).Text;

    if(!(textFromEditText.Equals(string.Empty)))
    {
        ListWhitText.Add(textFromEditText);

        try
        {
            _ListViewWhitTexts.Adapter = new AddItemArrayAdapter (this,Resource.Layout.newTextFromEdit , ListWhitText);

           catch (Exception ex)         
           {
              Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
           }
        }

    FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.textFromEditText).Text = string.Empty;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your implementation of `GetView()` in `AddItemArrayAdapter.cs` you'll notice that you call   `textView.Text = GetLastItem();`

`GetView()` is called for each row when the adapter is building the list. So each row will use the text from `GetLastItem();`

`GetView()`'s first parameter is an int called position which is what item in the list it is currently building the UI for. Change the above line to this

> textView.Text = _ListOfText[position];

and each row will look up the correct index of the string array.

Comment: Now the problem is image from background. Is changing :(

Comment: I don't really see any code related to the background from your post. I think you should ask a new question with the related code and more description on what the problem is.

Comment: I create two Layout files. BlueBalls.axml and GrayBalls.axml (`android:background="@drawable/BlueBalls"` and `android:background="@drawable/GrayBalls"` , but when add new item the background all rows is changed.